# rerender on fullcalendar.io removeing all events

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am not sure how to approach fullcalender.io. As I will be refreshing the calender, I thought I would return the calendar object like this.

```js
var calendar = function (eventsObj) {
    console.log(eventsObj);
    return new FullCalendar.Calendar(document.getElementById("calendar"), {
        plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid'],
        defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
        defaultDate: new Date().getDate(),
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        events: eventsObj
    });
}
```

I did it this way because I need to refresh all my events inside a bootstrap modal.
When Modal is shown I recall this function.

```js
 $("#assignModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
            calendar(globalEvents).rerenderEvents();
```

Here `globalEvents` is an array with all the events.
I initially render the calendar like this

```js
window.onload = function () {
    calendar(globalEvents).render();
};
```

Issue is that the calendar renders but It does not have any events whereas if I just render the calendar, it keeps all the events. I checked on their docs, they have different features in different versions. Any ideas? please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like below just remove old events attach new events and rerenderevents

below is some APIS which will help you

```
//remove old data
$('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');

//Getting new event json data
$("#fullCalendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', response);

//Updating new events
$('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');

//getting latest Events
$('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );

//getting latest Resources
$('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchResources' );
```

here is working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/znv2c1jy/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much for replying but this will only work if I use v3 (I suppose). This is why I mentioned that their docs are a little messy for my taste.

Comment: so what you are looking for?

Comment: how do i remove all events and re do with new events. I did more googling and for v4 they have a ```calendar.addEvent( event [, source ] )``` but How do I remove all events?

Comment: $('#fullCalendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents'); see this it will remove all events

Comment: have you seen a fiddle?

Comment: Yes. it definitely works but it works with the v3. Anyway that helped alot.

Comment: All this code is for v3, so not much use to OP who is using v4. They are very different - check the updated documentation!

Answer (score 1):

So basically according to the v4 guides.

```js
calendar.getEventSources().forEach(function (item) {
                item.remove();
            });
            calendar.addEventSource(globalEvents);
```

This is how you would have to remove the events and render new ones. Here `globalEvents` is just an array I use to keep track of my refreshed events.